# Slideshow images in react.js

Tags: reactjs, image, slideshow

I have seen an example of the type of slideshow that I want to achieve using color, looks like this:

```
const colors = ["#0088FE", "#00C49F", "#FFBB28"];

function Slideshow() {
  return (
    <div className="slideshow">
      <div className="slideshowSlider">
        {colors.map((backgroundColor, index) => (
          <div
            className="slide"
            key={index}
            style={{ backgroundColor }}
          ></div>
        ))}
      </div>
```

My question is, how could I do the same but using imported Images instead of colors?

```
import Image from '../images/guitar.jpg'
import Image2 from '../images/bass.jpg'
import Image3 from '../images/drums.jpg'
```